# PhoneGap Conversion - HTML to .apk

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am turning a HTML app into a .apk using https://build.phonegap.com and everything works great appart from my file selector.

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="file">
```

I want to be able to select images only (it doesnt matter if it can select more - but its the images I am looking for) from both camera and file system..

In the web version http://carbonyzed.co.uk/websites/assent/1/photos.html this works great from my phone, but when converted to .apk, this functionality is lost, and I can't seem to find anything on here, or online relating to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for me, the input file doesn't work in Phonegap.

You need use the Phonegap API to get picture and select the source where come from, like photolibrary, camera or savedphotoalbum.

See more info about camera.getPicture: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture
and about Camera.PictureSourceType parameter of cameraOptions method: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions

Comment: Correct, input with a type of file does not work on Android. It doesn't work on most mobile browsers. If you just want to get pictures then you should use camera.getPicture() with the PHOTOLIBRARY  option.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the Child Browser system like so

In the head

```
<script src="childbrowser.js"></script>
```

in the body

```
<button class="button-big"     onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('URL_TO_GO_HERE',
                                    { showAddress: false });" style="width: 100%;">UPLOAD     PHOTOS</button>
```

which has a standard fileuploader like

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="file">
```

then it let me select from root storage, works in phonegap 2.2 onwards on both iOS and Android OS

To capture an image I used this in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }       
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureImage() {
    // Launch device camera application, 
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 images
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}

// Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });   
}

</script>
```

and this in the body

```
<input type="button" class="button-big" style="width: 100%;" onclick="captureImage();" value="TAKE PHOTO">
```

copy and past and it works a dream,

Check it out in this image

[image]

any questions, just email comment,

or email me... support@carbonyzed.co.uk